# display fragment after data loading, recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView to display data in fragment, but firstly I need to download this data from server. Is it possible to make something like this:

1. User want to switch to fragment
2. ProgressBar is visible on sceen until data is downloaded
3. Fragment is displayed with all the data

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: load the data beforehand (in an AsyncTask, with a dialog preferably), after it's done loading, pass the data to the your Fragment using a constructor method (or a regular method of your choice) and finally show the fragment.

Comment: @MikeAnderson What happen if user will switch to fragment before AsyncTask load the data??